# User installations are disabled via policy on the machine

Tags: node.js, cordova, installation, group-policy

I am creating a web app in Android using PhoneGap.

While installing *node.js*,*the installation gets failed showing me user installations are disabled via policy on the machine*.

How can i resolve it ?

Comment: Not programming related. Should be moved to superuser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi follow below steps

1. From the Start menu, click Run…
2. In the Run… command dialog, enter gpedit.msc
3. In the Group Policy Editor, select Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Installer
4. In the Extended Properties pane, double-click Prohibit User Installs
   Click Disabled
5. Click OK and close the Group Policy Editor

Run the installer again..

Answer (score 13):

I tried @PeacefulWarrior solution mentioned above but it did not work for me on Windows 7 machine.

So I tried changing this setting from registry, and it worked.

Go to key **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Installer**

Change the **DisableUserInstalls** value to 0.